# using CMake for making  a project which includes MFC

Tags: mfc, cmake

I have a project in which I have to use a COM Module which uses MFC. I use CMake for making my   project. Can anybody tell me what I have to include into my CMakeLists.txt so that I can use MFC in my project?

Answer (score 7):

You need to add `_AFXDLL` to the preprocessor definitions and set the CMake variable `CMAKE_MFC_FLAG` to `1` for the static MFC library, or `2` for the shared one.

```
add_definitions(-D_AFXDLL)
set(CMAKE_MFC_FLAG 1)
```

For further info run

```
cmake --help-variable CMAKE_MFC_FLAG
```

Comment: Also, make sure to add `WIN32` to your `add_executable` or you'll probably get a link error.

Comment: @seeker incredible. A comment on an unaccepted answer from back in '12-'13 solves my problem. Thanks man!